# What can I do about Mechanize waiting on an unresponsive web site?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mechanize

I noticed that when I fetch a site that is not responding using [Mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/), it just keeps on waiting.

How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: What is the site and what is the error?

Comment: Example for a problematic site:  karusela.­net

Comment: -1 Your question is too vague. You don't show what you've tried so far. Also "Question" is redundant in the question title, as everything in Stack Overflow is supposed to be a question.

Comment: "everything in Stack Overflow is supposed to be a question." It is? It is! Except that, it's an exclamation! :-)

Comment: So how do explain the fact that I got an answer that solved my problem?

Comment: -100 for the reference to the Timeout module. I do an awful lot of network programming so something like Timeout is seductive as heck. When I recently found it, I put it in a lot of places and then I started getting lots of threading issues. I just found this: http://www.mikeperham.com/2015/05/08/timeout-rubys-most-dangerous-api/ which nicely tackles the issues as well as: http://jvns.ca/blog/2015/11/27/why-rubys-timeout-is-dangerous-and-thread-dot-raise-is-terrifying/ I'd strongly recommend you follow Mike Perham's advice and use the network settings at the client level instead. I'm about to

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's a couple ways to deal with it.

Open-Uri, and Net::HTTP have ways of passing in timeout values, which then tell the underlying networking stack how long you are willing to wait. For instance, Mechanize lets you get at its settings when you initialize an instance, something like:

```
mech = Mechanize.new { |agent|
  agent.open_timeout   = 5
  agent.read_timeout   = 5
}
```

It's all in the docs for `new` but you'll have to view the source to see what instance variables you can get at.

Or you can use Ruby's [`timeout`](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/timeout/1.9.2/frames) module:

```
require 'timeout'
status = Timeout::timeout(5) {
  # Something that should be interrupted if it takes too much time...
}
```

Comment: If they are it should be taken up with the Mechanize authors.

Comment: here is the explanation of what open_timeout and read_timeout is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17453099/ruby-savon-difference-between-read-timeout-and-open-timeout. but it's true, these parameters are ignored.

Answer (score 3):

http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/mechanize/Mechanize.html on this page there are 2 undocumented attributes `open_timeout` and `read_timeout`, try using them.

```
agent = Mechanize.new { |a| a.log = Logger.new("mech.log") }
agent.keep_alive=false
agent.open_timeout=15
agent.read_timeout=15
```

HTH