# How long block Net:http

Tags: ruby, timeout

How long can `Net:http` block my application?

```
url = "http://feeds.streams.xenim.de/live/binaergewitter/json/"
respons = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(url))
```

I found out that I can set:

`http.open_timeout` (Number of seconds to wait for the connection to open.) default: nil

`http.read_timeout` (Number of seconds to wait for one block to be read (via one read(2) call).) default: 60 seconds

Does this really mean that it wait forever and try to read 60 seconds?

And if I want that I got a timeout after 5 seconds should I better use something like:

```
open('http://stackoverflow.com', 'r', :read_timeout=>5).read
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `read_timeout` of `60` means that you will wait at max. 60 seconds for a response from the server before it timeouts.

To specify a timeout of 5 seconds, do:

```
conn = Net::HTTP.new('feeds.streams.xenim.de')
conn.read_timeout = 5
conn.get '/live/binaergewitter/json/'
```

`open_timeout` specifies the number of seconds to wait for the connection to open (ie. TCP handshake).

Comment: And what is with the `open_timeout`?

Comment: @Sirl33tname Added explanation. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17453099/ruby-savon-difference-between-read-timeout-and-open-timeout

Comment: So if I set `open_timeout` and `read_timeout` to 2 sec I got in worstcase after 4 sec a timeout?