# I want Mechanize to stop trying to open a URL if it's been trying for 60 seconds. How do I do this?

Tags: ruby, mechanize

Mechanize sometimes takes forever when trying to open some URLs. I want my Mechanize webcrawler to take 60 seconds maximum when trying to open a URL.

How do I do this?

Comment: Try looking around a bit previous answers on the subject like [This One](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582122/what-can-i-do-about-mechanize-waiting-on-an-unresponsive-web-site) or [Catching timeout errors with ruby mechanize](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425978/catching-timeout-errors-with-ruby-mechanize)  will probably resolve your issue.